# Hashicorp Vault cli return 403 when trying to use kv

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I set up vault backed by a consul cluster. I secured it with https and am trying to use the cli on a separate machine to get and set secrets in the kv engine. I am using version 1.0.2 of both the CLI and Vault server.

I have logged in with the root token so I should have access to everything. I have also set my VAULT_ADDR appropriately.

Here is my request:

`vault kv put secret/my-secret my-value=yea`

Here is the response:

```
Error making API request.

URL: GET https://{my-vault-address}/v1/sys/internal/ui/mounts/secret/my-secret
Code: 403. Errors:

* preflight capability check returned 403, please ensure client's policies grant access to path "secret/my-secret/"
```

I don't understand what is happening here. I am able to set and read secrets in the kv engine no problem from the vault ui. What am I missing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This was a result of me not reading documentation.

The request was failing because there was no secret engine mounted at that path.

You can check your secret engine paths by running `vault secrets list -detailed`

This showed that my kv secret engine was mapped to path `kv` not `secret` as I was trying.

Therefore running `vault kv put kv/my-secret my-value=yea` worked as expected.

Comment: I would combine this answer with the answer from @yan at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648532/2009612

Comment: Also, to keep mind, some of the tutorials use kv/ others use secret/ so you can't jump between them and cut and paste.

Answer (score 25):

You can enable secret engine for specific path

```
vault secrets enable -path=kv kv
```

https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/secrets-engines

Comment: For the original question we need: 'vault secrets enable -path=secret kv'

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `secret/my-secret` to whichever path you mounted when you enable the kv secret engine.

For example, if you enable the secret engine like this:

```
vault secrets enable -version=2 kv-v2
```

You should mount to `kv-v2` instead of `secret`

```
vault kv put kv-v2/my-secret my-value=yea
```