# Using Vault UI to get secrets

Tags: hashtable, vault

I have the following policies:

```
path "/kv/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}

path "/kv/data/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}
```

Using the CLI I and able to use the following command to get the secrets:
`vault kv get -mount=kv dev/db`

And it outputs the secrets correctly. The issue occurs when using the the UI
[image]

-With the input of `dev/db` I get `Ember Data Request POST /v1/sys/capabilities-self returned a 400 Payload (application/json) [object Object]`

-With the input of `/data/dev/db` I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.data')`

Any advice on how to access the secrets using the UI ?

Comment: Is this engine KVv2?

Comment: Yeah, it’s KVv2

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the state you are looking for. Let me share with you what i did:

First I specified in my terminal what I need in terms of my Vault:

```
export VAULT_TOKEN='the token I use to authenticate myself in the UI'
export VAULT_ADDR='my vault address'
```

Login myself in the same way i will do in the UI:

```
vault login -method=token token=$VAULT_TOKEN
```

Creating policy

```
vault policy write my-policy - << EOF  
path "/kv/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}

path "/kv/data/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}
EOF
```

Enabling secrets engine for specific path. As you can see in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312213/hashicorp-vault-cli-return-403-when-trying-to-use-kv)

```
vault secrets enable -path=kv kv
```

Inserting and reading secret:

```
vault kv put kv/dev/db value=yes
vault kv get -mount=kv dev/db
```

After all of this steps I can see the secret in:

- `VAULT_ADDR/ui/vault/secrets/kv/show/dev/db`

So, if **VAULT_ADDR** was `http://127.0.0.1:8200` the full path in the browser will be:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8200/ui/vault/secrets/kv/show/dev/db`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ...

```
path "/kv/data/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}
```

If you use...

```
path "/kv/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read","list", "update"]
}
```

...you see the keys on UI as listed.